# Jquery: Not Receiving Data from php page through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="response">
  </span>

  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#open-comm").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://en.wikilistia.com/fetch_comments.php",
      type: "POST",

      SUCCESS: function (responsedata) {
        $("#response").html(responsedata);
        alert("sucess");
      }
    });
  });
});
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Not Receiving responsedata from php page. In the browser php file showing data but through ajax not showing anything. 
What's the problem with PHP or Jquery code. I am trying first time this.

Comment: <img class="open-comm icon50" id="open-comm" src="/wp-content/themes/wikilistia/icons/comment.svg">  This is id code to click

Comment: javascript is case sensitive.  `SUCCESS` should be `success`. Beyond that add an error handler and provide more troubleshooting details

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#open-comm").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://en.wikilistia.com/fetch_comments.php",
      type: "POST",
      success: function (responsedata) {
        $("#response").html(responsedata);
        alert("sucess");
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="response"></span>
</body>
```

It's a typo SUCCESS should be success